# BuildConfig: Attribute value must be constant

Tags: android, gradle

I have a Maven Android project and I'm trying to convert it to Gradle. I'm using AndroidAnnotations.

In the Maven project, I have this interface:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = Constants.REST_ROOT_URL, converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface RestClient {
    //some methods
}
```

`Constants` is a util class where I store some configuration final variables, like the REST server URL or the database name and version.

I have discovered `BuildConfig` in Gradle and I'd like to use it.

I have put the code below in my `build.gradle` and the build creates the field properly.

```
 defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "REST_ROOT_URL", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
```

The problem is when I try to use `BuildConfig` like previous `Constants` class.

```
@Rest(rootUrl = BuildConfig.REST_ROOT_URL, converters = {MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class})
public interface RestClient {
    //some methods
}
```

In `rootUrl = BuildConfig.REST_ROOT_URL`, I'm getting the error:

`Attribute value must be constant`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved. I have realized that BuildConfig class wasn't being compiled properly because I forget the single quotes.

```
defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "REST_ROOT_URL", '"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
}
```